# HTTPS communication with EC2 Instance

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, firebase, amazon-ec2

I have my java spring project running successfully on AWS EC2 instance uploaded via elastic bean stalk but its endpoint is of the form http://...........
Now i have uploaded my angular project on firebase.

I could have uploaded it on AWS itself but it requires geolocation()  which requires HTTPS connection. when i connect my angular app to aws instance via endpoint it shows

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://aspertime-a3b60.firebaseapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://aspertime-env.x2enfd8jmj.ap-south1.elasticbeanstalk.com/employee/login?username=123&password=123'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

i have tried many times to solve this problem.

```
    -
```

Comment: "i have tried many times to solve this problem." how? What have you tried? Have you searched at all for the options available for enabling HTTPS on an Elastic Beanstalk app?

Comment: Place Load balancer on the top of Elastic beanstalk and integrate ssl from AWS ACM.

Comment: @Adiii can we please have a personal talk my email address is shubhintee@gmail.com .please reply if you can see this message.

Comment: @Adiii can i get a ssl certificate for this url => [link](https://aspertime-a3b60.firebaseapp.com) from aws acm

Comment: Yes sure but you can text me over LinkedIn, you can find my LinkedIn profile on my stackoverflow profile 

Comment: @Adiii i just sent you a request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as we discussed in the comment, follow these steps

- Create a Certificate from [AWS ACM](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/)
- Verify the certificate by adding an entry to your DNS provider
- Create Load balancer with https listener
- Place Load balancer on the top of Elastic beanstalk
- Update web-app to point New TLS endpoint